# Allow user to choose correct answer with accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the rails relations:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions,
                            reject_if: proc { |a| a[:content].blank? },
                            allow_destroy: true
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers,
                                reject_if: proc { |a| a[:content].blank? },
                                allow_destroy: true
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

How would a structure the model so when the user is in Quiz#edit or Quiz#new they can select which answer (with radio buttons) is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the `answers` table, add an additional attribute called 'is_correct_answer' that will be true only for one combination.

Comment: I think this is an extra join that is not required and can be avoided by other means

Comment: you can do the same in the answers table itself without an additional table